# Get contents of clicked link in external iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, hyperlink, click, external

I'm trying to get the text contents of a A (link) in an externally loaded site via an iframe.

What i'm trying to achieve is loading up an iframe so the admin person can click each title in the iframe and append it to a textarea inside my admin area (the parent page which loads the iframe). The iframe is from an external site which I have no control over.

Is this possible in jquery so I can override the click event of the iframes link (so the iframe doesn't visit the target page once clicked) and get the contents and append it to my list?

If it's not possible via jquery, is it possible using other methods do you know? I have some of this being done in xpath and php, but not ever site loads a unique list to make it reliable with automation.

Thanks for your help! Telling me if it's possible and point in the right direction would be awesome.

Comment: Try YQL https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible in accordance to the same-origin policy:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

One, rather 'hacky' (depending on your requirements), solution would be to implement a proxy, grab the markup from the external source server-side - and then render that onto your page (wouldn't need the iframe in this case). The markup is then, effectively, mimicked on your domain - meaning you have access to the DOM as if it were your own.

Comment: Thanks DeeMac, that should do the trick. I was afraid of the same-origin policy but worth asking as you've pointed me in the right direction. Thank you.